Remove all occurrence of specific character from strings surrounded by double quotes
I have below string (this is a single string - I've added newlines only for readability):
"someField0";"some value1; some value2; some value3; some value4";
"someField1";"some value1; some value2; some value3";
"someField2";"some value1; some value2";
"someField3";"some value123";

I need to get rid of any occurrence of ; character from quoted parts using regex / substitution.
Desired result is like below:
"someField0";"some value1 some value2 some value3 some value4";
"someField1";"some value1 some value2 some value3";
"someField2";"some value1 some value2";
"someField3";"some value123";

Is it possible to achieve this using only regex with substitution?
I have found several solutions like below, but all of them are capable to remove only one occurrence.
("[^",]+);([^"]+")

And then substitute with
$1 $2

I am searching of solution based on pure regex because I need to implement this inside SQL query using regex_replace function. This is a part of more complex parsing statement.

Regular expressions are not good at distinguishing inside and outside quotes. You should use some other tool, like a CSV parser.

Why do you need a pure regex solution? SQL queries can also use other functions, other tools or frameworks too. Which RDBMS do you use?

I am using Snowflake. Any idea to achieve desired result is more than welcome :)

All of the valid ; symbols are preceeded by ".  So just change them temporarily to somehting else.  Then you can just remove any remaining ; symbols then restore the valid ; symbols.

How will the input look when there is a literal double quote embedded in a quoted part? Is it escaped?

You could try using backreferences on capture groups. The idea is to stitch first and third capture group, and leave the second out.
select regexp_replace(str,'([^"])([;]+)([^"])','\\1\\3')


This is more elegant solution! And it works. Thank You @Rajat

It's relatively inefficient but you could make use of the fact that a character is within a substring enclosed in double-quotes if the remaining number of double quotes in the string is odd.
You therefore could replace matches of the regular expression
;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$)

with an empty string.
Demo.
The problem is that Snowflake regexp functions don't support non-capturing groups, lookaheads and lookbehinds. However, as pointed out by @GregPavli in a comment here, "Snowflake supports JavaScript and it supports all of these. You can write a JavaScript UDF to get non-capturing groups or lookarounds. I've also written a library of JavaScript UDFs that approximate the syntax of the Snowflake regexp functions as closely as possible that support these capabilities here".

Like @Bart McEndree suggested.
You may temporarily replace ; enclosed by "
Example :
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(text, '";"', '"""'), ';', ''), '"""', '";"') FROM <table>;

In this example, I temporarily replace ";" by """, but you may change that.

I've used this approach. Thanks guys.

You essentially have a CSV file. Since Python has a very capable csv parser, try that:
import csv 
from io import StringIO 

txt='''\
"someField0";"some value1; some value2; some value3; some value4";
"someField1";"some value1; some value2; some value3";
"someField2";"some value1; some value2";
"someField3";"some value123";
'''

r=csv.reader(StringIO(txt), delimiter=';')

for row in r:
    print(';'.join([f"\"{s.replace(";","")}\"" for s in row]))

Prints:
"someField0";"some value1 some value2 some value3 some value4";""
"someField1";"some value1 some value2 some value3";""
"someField2";"some value1 some value2";""
"someField3";"some value123";""

Since you have ; at the end of each line, that is why you have the blank field at the end of each line. You can remove the trailing ; in the input or test for a blank field on output if you don't want that.

Yes, but I need to do this inside SQL select statement. My string is an varchar column which I need to parse.
